# Get the "retouched" image from ALAssetRepresentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, alassetslibrary

Given an `ALAssetRepresentation`, is it possible to get its **full resolution retouched** image?

If I use the method `fullResolutionImage` I get the full resolution image, but *unadjusted in any way.*

If I use the method `fullScreenImage`I get the retouched image, but *reduced to an appropriate for displaying full screen*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s not that easy, but you can. Notice that this will also apply any cropping done by the user in the Photos.app:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *representation = asset.defaultRepresentation;
CGImageRef fullResolutionImage = CGImageRetain(representation.fullResolutionImage);
// AdjustmentXMP constains the Extensible Metadata Platform XML of the photo
// This XML describe the transformation done to the image.
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform
// Have in mind that the key is not exactly documented.
NSString *adjustmentXMP = [representation.metadata objectForKey:@"AdjustmentXMP"];

NSData *adjustmentXMPData = [adjustmentXMP dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *__autoreleasing error = nil;
CGRect extend = CGRectZero;
extend.size = representation.dimensions;
NSArray *filters = [CIFilter filterArrayFromSerializedXMP:adjustmentXMPData inputImageExtent:extend error:&error];
if (filters)
{
  CIImage *image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:fullResolutionImage];
  CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
  for (CIFilter *filter in filters)
  {
    [filter setValue:image forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    image = [filter outputImage];
  }

  CGImageRelease(fullResolutionImage);
  fullResolutionImage = [context createCGImage:image fromRect:image.extent];
}

// At this moment fullResolutionImage will be the filtered image, or the full
// resolution one if no filters were applied.
// You will need to CGImageRelease fullResolutionImage after you have finished
// working with it.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works. But I think there is a memory leak, due to the `CGImageRetain()` which is never released if `filters == nil`. Why do you retain this?

Comment: Yes, that was part of my code. I probably create an `UIImage` later and then release `fullResolutionImage`. The extra `CGImageRetain` at the top is needed to simplify the code, since you need to do a `createGCImage:fromRect:`, you are going to need to release it, so the extra retain is cancelled after this code.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. We do a `CGImageRetain()` so we can release it whether it has been created with `createCGImage:fromRect:`or not. Therefore, the important thing to note is that _after_ the last use of  `fullResolutionImage` we have to release it. Thanks.