# Is there a way to detect whether a photo in the photo library has ever been edited?

Tags: ios, objective-c

By editing, I mean any changes made via the edit menu in the built-in photos application. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this link:
[Get the "retouched" image from ALAssetRepresentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086093/get-the-retouched-image-from-alassetrepresentation)

The following should do:

```
BOOL isAssetEdited(ALAsset *asset)
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *assetRep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
    NSString *adjustmentXMP = [assetRep.metadata objectForKey:@"AdjustmentXMP"];
    return adjustmentXMP != nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally your Asset Library Object contains both original and modified image. So if your goal is to always have the original or the modified it's possible.

And if you want to know if it have been modified, maybe you can make the difference between both.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. Do you know of a way to get images (of the same size) for both the original and the modified? If resizing is involved, the comparing result might not be trust-worthy. Right?

Comment: Yes but if resizing is involved, you are sure the image have been modified isn't ? After all it's part of the edit menu.
Otherwise I don't think you can get the image with just some modification but not the others.

Comment: Here is my point: To compare two images as suggested, we would need two images of the same size, and I haven't found API for that. If we resize the images to the same size before comparing, the comparing result would depend on the resizing algorithm used, thus not trust-worthy.

Comment: What about just convert your image to some `NSData` and look if it's the same ?

Comment: There is no need to compare NSData of two images of different size. Most likely they won't match. That doesn't necessarily mean the image has been edited.