# CIContext createCGImage returns nil in iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, alassetslibrary, ciimage

I am using the code provided in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18086093/get-the-retouched-image-from-alassetrepresentation).

It works for most images, but when I had an image that I cropped using the built-in Photos app, I kept getting nil from the `[context createCGImage:fromRect]` call.  After spending a lot of time trying various things and coming up empty, I decided to try it on my iPhone 5, and to my surprise, it worked!

Is this really expected to fail in iOS Simulator?  Or is there something else I need to do to make it work in the simulator?

Comment: Can you step through the code and see if any part of it is failing or returning nil when run in the simulator? For example is the XMP file coming back nil for some reason in the simulator? It seems like you need to narrow down which part is failing.

Comment: All the steps are performing as expected. The `image` passed into `[context createCGImage:fromRect]` is valid, and `image.extent` is valid as well.  It's only this call that then returns nil.  The cropped image I created using the Photos app ended up with 2 filters, and feeding `createCGImage` with the output of either filter returns nil, even though the filter produces non-nil results.